# When user input the numbers it should get expand

Tags: python

I want to represent a user entered number in expanded form.
For eg: user_input = 12345
Output = 1 * 10000 + 2 * 1000 + 3 * 100 + 4 * 10 + 5 * 1

Comment: show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

iterate through the string form of the number backwards, use the place of the number to get the power of 10, add to `result`, then join reversed `result` using pluses

```
user_input = 12345

result = []
for i, num in enumerate(str(user_input)[::-1]):
    result.append(f'{num} * {10 ** i}')

print(' + '.join(result[::-1]))
```